# Swapping pairs in a stack of integers?

Tags: java, integer, stack

We were given this assignment..

Write a method switchPairs that takes a stack of integers as a parameter and that switches successive pairs of numbers starting at the bottom of the stack.

Ex:
[1,2,3,4,5,6] becomes [2,1,4,3,6,5]

But we were also told that we can only use one queue for auxiliary storage...I don't see how that can be possible? Wouldn't we need at least 2 since we want to swap pairs of numbers and you can't choose an index of a stack to pop?

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. You can't choose the order of popping, but so what? You just have to push them back on the stack in the right order, which you can easily do because the auxilliary storage is unrestricted.

Comment: Could you clarifiy what you mean by unrestricted? I thought I could only push them as a i remove them from the front of the queue?

Comment: What type of "Queue" are we talking about here?  I'm assuming that for an assignment, this Queue is the most basic one -- FIFO, operations on both ends, etc.  If it has more features than this (such as a Deques), then it would be quite simple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) pop all the values from the stack onto the queue.

2) for every pair of values in the queue, push the pair back onto the stack in reverse order.

Using the comments below, we note that pushing all the elements onto the queue and back to the list will reverse the order.

Then, we can push the values onto the list once more and note that the list will now be in the correct order and apply 2.

```
Stack bottom 1,2,3,4,5,6 top
Queue front 6,5,4,3,2,1 end
Stack bottom 6,5,4,3,2,1 top
Queue front 1,2,3,4,5,6 end
```

Now apply 2)

```
Stack bottom 2,1,4,3,6,5 top
```

Comment: No...it's a little more involved than that.

Comment: Doing so would reverse the order of the entire stack.  For example,
[1, 2, 3, 4] would return [3, 4, 1, 2]

Comment: @Makoto does it have to be a Java `Queue` or can it be a java `List`?

Comment: I'm sorry -- [1, 2, 3, 4] does not return [3, 4, 1, 2].  It should return [4, 3, 2, 1] unless you add a few more clever steps in it (popping all elements of a stack to a queue, removing all the elements of the queue and placing it back to the stack will only reverse the elements).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need more than one queue for this.  You just have to be careful where you insert your elements into your queue.

Here's a quick runthrough:

- Start popping off elements of your stack.
- The second element you pop, you want to insert in front of the one you popped previously.
- After that's done, iterate the queue in a reverse order (use a Deque or sort the queue in reverse order), pushing all of the elements into the stack.

Here's a code snippet.

```
public <T> Deque<T> switchPairs(final Deque<T> stack) {
    final Deque<T> result = new ArrayDeque<>();
    if(stack.size() % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know how to handle odd sized lists.");
    }
    List<T> buffer = new LinkedList<>();
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        buffer.add(stack.pop());
        buffer.add(lastIndex, stack.pop());
        lastIndex += 2;
    }
    for(final ListIterator<T> listIterator = buffer.listIterator(buffer.size()); listIterator.hasPrevious();) {
        result.push(listIterator.previous());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The process is explained - there's really not a whole lot to explain besides the bullet points I've elaborated on already.  Further, if they were to verbatim copy this into their program, they'd be in for a world of hurt on odd numbered lists, as well as the fact that this is easily searchable.

Comment: My result isn't correct, at least according to my code....also the queue I get stops at 10 if the stack was greater than 10?

Answer (score 0):

[`Deques`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) support operations at both ends.  So take advantage of that.

Pop items off your stack, and alternately `addFirst` and `addLast` them to your queue.  So a stack of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` turns into `[2,4,6,5,3,1]`.

Now, reverse the process, removing elements from the queue and pushing them back onto the stack.  The last operation we did was `addLast`; if we therefore start with `removeFirst` it effectively swaps the order of each pair. (this all assumes an even number of elements in your stack)

Visualization:

```
stack           deque
[1,2,3,4,5,6]   []
[1,2,3,4,5]     >[6]
[1,2,3,4]       [6,5]<
[1,2,3]         >[4,6,5]
[1,2]           [4,6,5,3]<
[1]             >[2,4,6,5,3]
[]              [2,4,6,5,3,1]<

[2]             <[4,6,5,3,1]
[2,1]           [4,6,5,3]>
[2,1,4]         <[6,5,3]
[2,1,4,3]       [6,5]>
[2,1,4,3,6]     <[5]
[2,1,4,3,6,5]   []>
```

Comment: Java's `Queue` does not. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 0):

We know one crucial fact: moving all elements of a stack onto a queue and then back onto a stack would simply reverse the order of the elements of the original stack.  For example, [1, 2, 3, 4] would yield [4, 3, 2, 1].

Here is one way we can do it:

`1) Pop and enqueue all elements of the stack to the queue.`

`2) Remove elements off of the queue two at a time and push it to the stack.  By our crucial fact, we know that these two elements now have their orders reversed.  Add the two values back onto the queue.`

`3) Repeat step two until all pairs have been cycled through.`

`4) Remove all elements of our queue and push it to the stack.  We are almost done -- from our crucial fact, we know that this is our desired output in reverse.`

`5) Pop all elements of our stack and enqueue it.  Remove all elements and push it back to the stack.  This reverses everything and we have our desired output.`

Here it is as an example.  Say we begin with a stack [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], with 1 being the top of the stack...

```
(Step 0) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (Stack)

(Step 1) [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] (Queue) (1 is beginning of queue)

(Step 2) [6, 5, 4, 3] (Queue) [2, 1] (Stack)

(Step 2) [1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3] (Queue)

(Step 3) [1, 2, 6, 5] (Queue) [4, 3] (Stack)

(Step 3) [3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5] (Queue)

(Step 3) [3, 4, 1, 2] (Queue) [6, 5] (Stack)

(Step 3) [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2] (Queue)

(Step 4) [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2] (Stack)

(Step 5) [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5] (Queue)

(Step 5) [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5] (Stack)
```

This is assuming, of course, that we only have your basic FIFO Queue and LIFO Stack available (no access to Deques or other linked lists).